# Append row to each category basis column calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, dataframe

I have data in the format:

[image]

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS total;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE total
    (
     Person varchar(100),
     Spend_category varchar(100),
     Amount numeric(38,12),
     Salary numeric(38,12)
    );
   INSERT INTO total (Person, Spend_category ,Amount, Salary)
   VALUES ('A','',0,2000),('A','Grocery',50,0),('A','Transport',20,0), ('A','Rent',100,0),('B','',0,3000),('B','Grocery',60,0),('B','Rent',150,0);
```

I would require a separate category "Rest" to each person. Rest is Salary minus all spends. Is there any way we can do it?
I want the output to be:

[image]

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: `CREATE TEMP TABLE` is not valid mysql; what database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assumng you're using MySQL 8+ or a DBMS that supports window functions, one option is as follows:

```
select Person,
  case when amount = 0 then 'Rest' else Spend_Category end Spend_category,
  case when amount = 0 then salary 
  - Sum(amount) over (partition by person) else amount end Amount
from total;
```